# Decoding Json not working, not giving error either

Tags: json, swift, codable

Im trying to decode the following json:

```
    [
        {
            "breeds":[
            {
            "weight":{
            "imperial":"65 - 75",
            "metric":"29 - 34"
            },
            "height":{
            "imperial":"21 - 28",
            "metric":"53 - 71"
            },
            "id":14,
            "name":"American Foxhound",
            "country_code":"US",
            "bred_for":"Fox hunting, scent hound",
            "breed_group":"Hound",
            "life_span":"8 - 15 years",
            "temperament":"Kind, Sweet-Tempered, Loyal, Independent, Intelligent, Loving"
            }
            ],
            "id":"p4xvDeEpW",
            "url":"https://cdn2.thedogapi.com/images/p4xvDeEpW.jpg",
            "width":680,
            "height":453
        }
    ]
```

I have my Models set as:

```
struct Request: Decodable {
    let response: [Response]
}

struct Response: Decodable {
    let breeds: [Dog]
    let url: String
}

struct Dog: Decodable {
    let weight: Measurement
    let height: Measurement
    let name: String
    let countryCode: String?
    let breedGroup: String
    let lifeSpan: String
    let temperament: String
    let origin: String?
}

struct Measurement: Decodable {
    let imperial: String
    let metric: String
}
```

I call the API as follows:

```
func fetchDogs(with request: URLRequest, completion: @escaping (([Dog]?, String?, Error?) -> ())) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

        guard let data = data,
            let request = try? decoder.decode(Request.self, from: data) else {
                completion(nil, nil, error)
                return
        }

        completion(request.response[0].breeds, request.response[0].url, nil)
        }.resume()
}
```

But it always hits the guard `completion(nil, nil, error)` line and I'm not sure why I'm not sure how to pull apart the first few lines of the JSON to start off with. Using:

```
struct Request: Decodable {
    let response: [Response]
}
```

doesn't seem right. If I update the request to decode the `Response` struct instead it still hits the guard.

My request builder looks like:

```
struct RequestBuilder {
    private let baseURLString: String

    static var defaultBuilder: RequestBuilder {
        return RequestBuilder(
            baseURLString: Constant.URL.dogsBase
        )
    }

    func dogsRequest() -> URLRequest {
        return dogRequest(path: Constant.Path.search)
    }

    private func dogRequest(path: String) -> URLRequest {
        guard var components = URLComponents(string: baseURLString) else {
            preconditionFailure(Constant.PreconditionFailure.baseURL)
        }

        components.path = path

        guard let url = components.url else {
            preconditionFailure(Constant.PreconditionFailure.baseURL)
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue(Constant.Key.dogs, forHTTPHeaderField: "x-api-key")

        return request
    }
}
```

The api can be found [here](https://thedogapi.com/)

Comment: How do you expect to get an error when you mask decoding errors with the `try?`? You should put your decoding code in a `do-catch` block, change the `try?` to `try` and check the actual error message.

Comment: You should use `decoder.decode([Response].self, from: data)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when you pass `Request.self` to `decode.decode`, `JSONDecoder` expects to find a `Dictionary` whose key is `response` due to your declaration of `Request`.

You simply need to pass `[Response].self` to the `decode` method.

```
guard let data = data,
    let request = try? decoder.decode([Response].self, from: data) else {
        completion(nil, nil, error)
        return
}
```

If you didn't mask the decoding error using `try?`, you'd see the issue immediately from the error message:

> typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

You should always use a normal `try` statement in a `do-catch` block when you are unsure about whether your code will work or not, since this way you can actually see the error message. `JSONDecoder` throws pretty useful errors, so I'd suggest you never mask them into a `nil` using `try?`.